# Drag and drop event in JavaFX TableView

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, tableview, javafx-2, javafx

I would like to add Drag and Drop support to my `JavaFX` application. My requirement is that if someone drags files from Native file system and drops to the `JavaFX` **TableView** then it must recognize the drop event and how can i get the list of drpped files.

Comment: It's much easier in SWT, but maybe this one can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192371/dragn-drop-files-from-the-os-to-java-application-swing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the official JavaFX 2 docs.

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/drag_drop/jfxpub-drag_drop.htm

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/drag_drop/HelloDragAndDrop.java.html

So you can understand the methods you'll need to handle the drag events:

target.setOnDragOver

target.setOnDragEntered

target.setOnDragExited

target.setOnDragDropped

Then with the [DragEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/DragEvent.html) on these events you can use the getDragboard() to access the drag content, which inherits [Clipboard](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/Clipboard.html). From here, you have some methods like [getFiles](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/Clipboard.html#getFiles%28%29), which is what you need.

Comment: Yes, It's working. Thanks for the reply.

Can I do the reverse? I mean drags objects(Rows) from `JavaFX` TableView and drops to Native file system.

Comment: The Dragboard should be standard, so in the first link I gave, there is a "source.setOnDragDetected", where you put some content in the Dragboard (you can use putFiles, for instance):  /* Put a string on a dragboard */
        ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
        content.putString(source.getText());
        db.setContent(content);